# How to create a json data using two arrays and return it to ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

key:`[id,name,address]`

value:`[7,John,NewYork]`

I wish to create a json data like`{"id": 7, "name": "John", "address": "NewYork"}` using for(...){...},

and then return it to ajax

```
$.ajax({                                
    //what kind of format should json data be here? 
    data:??json data??,
    dataType: 'json',
});
```

Please help me

Answer (score 4):

To the first part of your question:

You could use [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and assign all properties with the correspondet value.

```js
var key = ['id', 'name', 'address'],
    value = [7, 'John', 'New York'],
    object = {};

key.forEach(function (k, i) {
    object[k] = value[i];
})

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: You could also use `Array#reduce` when creating `object` in order to avoid the standalone `forEach`. https://jsfiddle.net/5qhyp9eL/1/

Comment: Thank you very much,I've solved my problem according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You could:

- iterate through both arrays...
- ...add the 1st array element to an empty obj as a key...
- ...and assign the 2nd array element to the 1st array element as it's value.
- Each iteration will be paired as key/value when stringified as a JSON.

I'm surprised it actually worked, take a look at the demo below:

### SNIPPET

```js
var x = ['id', 'name', 'address'];

var y = [7, 'John', 'NewYork'];

function arrMerge(k, v) {

  var obj = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {

    obj[k[i]] = v[i];
  }

  return obj;
}

var z = arrMerge(x, y);

var json = JSON.stringify(z);

console.log(json);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping,$.ajax({...data:json,...}),it returns data successfully.

Comment: You're welcome, sir. I was about to do the AJAX part, but I see you have got that part handled.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a general function that zips two arrays together into an object if they're of equal length (also assuming they're in the correct order).

```
function zip(arr1, arr2) {
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;
  const obj = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    const key = arr1[i];
    obj[key] = arr2[i];
  }
  return obj;
}

zip(arr1, arr2); // { id: 7, name: "John", address: "NewYork" }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1hh1c0tx/2/)

You can then use that object as the value of `data` in your AJAX process.

> data
>
> Type: PlainObject or String or Array
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string.

[jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: According to your demo,I am able to  understand the construting process of obj step by step.

Answer (score 0):

I guess unlike forEach, since it returns the result, `Array.prototype.reduce()` comes very handy for these operations. You can even use it at the stage of declaring your JSON data (`jData` here).

```js
var   key = ['id', 'name', 'address'],
    value = [7, 'John', 'New York'],
    jData = JSON.stringify(key.reduce((p,c,i) => {p[c] = value[i]; return p},{}));
document.write("<pre>" + jData + "</pre>");
```